# Delete if duplicate in 1 column based on another column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to delete data from a table where an ID is duplicate but keeping another column at a certain value

```
key .   id .    info .    flag
1 .     A .     apple .   y
2 .     B .     banana .  n
3 .     B .     banana .  y
4 .     C .     orange .  n
```

I'd like to delete row 2 where "id" is duplicate and keep flag value as "y". the table is >100K rows

I've tried various combinations of DISTINCT and GROUP BYs without a great result

Comment: First try to write a `SELECT` query that returns the rows you want to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a group by, count and having for filter the possible id
if you want delete the value with y

```
  delete from 
  my_table where id in (
     select t.id from(
      select id
      from my_table 
      group by id
      having count(*) > 1
  )  t 
  and flag ='y')
```

otherwise  if you want keep the y then

```
  delete from 
  my_table where id in (
     select t.id from(
      select id
      from my_table 
      group by id
      having count(*) > 1
  )  t 
  and flag <>'y')
```

Comment: From the question's text I would say the OP wants to keep the records having `y` in the `flag` column, not to delete them...

Comment: @axiac  .. thanks  .. answer  updated  for both cases

Comment: the SELECT query works for the records, the problem though is this results in this error "You can't specify target table 'my_table' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: @scaisEdge i tried changing the inner my_table to { (SELECT * FROM my_table) as t } with no luck

Comment: it worked but only if i reverse the order of the clauses between the "and"